# reactjs does not store the last character in useState when typing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a frontend application with react

i want to store the value of phone on useState but i am not getting the expected result

The last character typed does not show

I have used callback to display the same result

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react'
    export const terr = () => {
        const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState({})
    
        const handleChange = (value) => {
            console.log(`selected ${value}`);
            setSelectedData(selectedData => ({
                ...selectedData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }));
            console.log(`selected data `, selectedData);
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <input name="phone" value={selectedData} onChange={handleChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted to achieve

```
export const Server = () => {
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedData({ ...selectedData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="phone" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note that the `console.log` inside the `handleChange` function always shows an "old" `selectedData` value because `setSelectedData` is async, try logging it with `useEffect` or directly inside the JSX to confirm

Comment: Pedantic complaint here, but `setSelectedData` ***is not*** `async`, it's a completely synchronous function. React state updater functions are not declared `async` nor do they return any Promise object, they just enqueue a state update. It may help to think of them more as requests to React to update the state at the next earliest convenience.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be wrong with your code is two things:

1. The `value` property on the `input` is not needed
2. The `handleChange` function should take a parameter of `event` (see [HTMLElement: change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#text_input_element))

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504979/128346
export const App: FC = () => {
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState<{
    phone?: string;
    words?: string;
  }>({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setSelectedData({
      ...selectedData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`selected data `, selectedData);
  }, [selectedData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        name="phone"
        value={selectedData.phone ?? ''}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        name="words"
        value={selectedData.words ?? ''}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**sandboxed demo of the above in action**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yhksn3?file=src%2FApp.tsx

**video demo of the above in action**
https://www.loom.com/share/4751379be5c04f10adcb61e241551b90

---

Comment: #2 is the answer. #1 is debatable. IME it's *always* better to make your `<input>`s fully-controlled if their changes are going to be reflected in your component's state. An uncontrolled input becomes a pain when you have any other interactions that are meant to modify its state. See https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable - IMO, OP should use `<input name="phone" value={selectedData.phone || ''} onChange={handleChange} />`

Comment: I believe OP is using the `onChange` event object with `[e.target.name]: e.target.value` and it is just that they've a typo in the post, their state is ***obviously*** getting updated correctly. This answer doesn't address the question at all though as to *why* the last character entered is missing.